# Java - OpenGL set offset for center (0,0) coordinates

Tags: java, opengl, viewport, offset, jogl

I am doing something with JOGL libraries (forced to) and I can't figure out how to offset the center zero coordinates. I would like to offset them to the bottom of my viewport, in the method

`public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height)`

but I can't google any way to translate int height into any meaningfull offset float coordinates.

edit:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
glu.gluPerspective(45.0, width / (float) height, 0.1, 100.0); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense.  The JOGL `reshape` method sets up OpenGL's viewport, which controls where inside of the drawable you're permitted to render.  Usually, most applications set that to the size of the window.  However, that doesn't specify where a point (for example) rendered at (0,0) would appear.  The _projection transformation_ controls that, which is also probably set within `reshape`, but isn't the viewport.  Can you say if you've set the viewport (e.g., with `glViewport`), or specified the projection transform?

Comment: Edited, I have just added the relevant section, the problem is that I got this code few hours ago and never done graphics before. I have not been able to find how to convert between window size in pixels and the  internal float positioning system.

Comment: gluLookAt seems to be the right method to use, but I still have a problem determining the right coordinates using int width and int height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using

glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 1, 0, 0.42, 0, 0, 1, 0);

Didn't realize the offset wasn't relative.